# Join two JPA bidirectionally having same col names?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've two table

```
    @Entity
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = "one", attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("two")})
    @Table(name = "one")
    One.class {

   @Id
    private sno;
    
    private String version;
    
    @Column(name = "bgn_no")
    private String bgnNo;

    @OnetoOne(cascade = CascadeType.All, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bgn_no", referenceColumnName = "bgn_no", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Two two;
    
    
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "two")
    Two.class {

   @Id
    private dim_no;
    
    @Column(name = "bgn_no")
    private String bgnNo;
    
    private location;
    private region;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "two")    -> issue
    private One one;               -> issue
    
    }
```

repository

```
BGNRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<One, String> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "one")
    One finfbyBgnNo(String no);

}
```

calling above repository using `servcieBGNRepository.finfbyBgnNo(String no, String ver)`

There are some other columns too in entities, but am joining on the basis `bgn_no` col. This col is present in both tables with same names. Above repository works fine only when `-> issue` lines are removed from above code, else giving below error

Getting error

```
Error Accessing field (private Two.bgn_no] by reflection for persistent property [Two#bgn_no], nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private  Two.bgn_no ] by reflectionfor persistent property[ Two#bgn_no]
```

I'm literally stuck on this issue. Can anyone suggest what can be done.
I've tried adding getter/setter too. But still same issue.

Comment: If in `Two.class` you remove the mapping for `private One one;`, are you then able to fetch an instance of `One` with a reference to `Two`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, yes correct

Comment: And are you able to fetch an instance on `Two` with a reference to `One`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  I get error when  I call just the above mentioned repository. So in that case, I think its pulling Two's instance in One and giving error (mentioned in question)

Comment: Can you provide the full entities? As of now, you are missing getter/setter, an `@Id`, you have a few typos and the class definition doesn't look like java. Also include the full stacktrace/error

Comment: updated @Ids in both entities and error is same which is mentioned. Any clue what's causing this issue ? Is it a bug ?

Comment: Dejavu. Do you have the stack trace where this exception is thrown? The query executed? What happens if you read in Two or One normally - say with just a normal find by id query? Your entity graph is likely the problem, as you tell it to bring in 'two' but ignore the one writeable mapping to the foreign key value it would need to use to query for Two instances. I suspect fetching the "bgnNo" attribute in your graph might help. It could also be that you are not referencing the ID values in your foreign keys; I don't know what type sno and dim_no are, but they are likely being used by default.